# How to solve an equation including both summation and product notation?

Tags: summation, notation

In what order should I solve the following equation? (I'm looking for a BEDMAS-type advice)

$$F_1=bcedw\sum_{x=1}^6 n(1-n)^{x-1}\prod_{z=1}^x p_z  $$

z is 2 to 6. I have all the values and corresponding answer, and am happy to provide them if it adds value to the question.

However, I haven't been able to get the correct answer myself. I've tried:

- first doing the summation for all 6 values of x and multiplying it by the product of the 6 values
- for each value of x, calculating the summation and the product and then summing those

I'm an ecologist posting for the first time in the Mathematics site, please let me know if I can improve this question, and thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: @Yves Daoust Can you give that a full edit?

Comment: @idk: mh, what more do you want ?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! What does "bcedw" mean ?

Comment: @Peter, thanks! Each letter represents a different value: b is breeding survival (0.72), c is clutch size (4.3), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first scalar factors apply to the whole summation. The summation is made of six terms, each with a factor that multiplies a product of an increasing number of $p_z$.

Hence you evaluate the partial products of $p_z$, multiply them by $n$ and the relevant power of $1-n$. Sum these six terms and multiply by the initial factors.